# Get details from MySQL table like length, value

Tags: php, mysql

I am interested in getting details from a Mysql table like it's type, length, value etc... in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database, which contains information about the schema of all other database objects.

You can also use a `DESCRIBE TABLE` or `SHOW CREATE TABLE` query then parse the resulting string in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

As a starter for ten...

```
EXPLAIN <tablename>;
```

...will get you the basic structure, etc.

Answer (score 0):

use [mysql_list_fields](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-fields.php)

Edit: I just saw that mysql_list_fields is deprecated now, but on that page is a section `Alternate to deprecated mysql_list_fields()`, and you can see how to do it. Also, take a look at `mysql_field_flags`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a database named Accounts and a Table inside of it named Users you could do the following:
DATABASE: accounts
TABLE: users

To see the information for all Tables inside the accounts Database: **SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM accounts;**

This would show you data length for example among other information.

To see the information for a specific table (the user table in this case) do: **SHOW COLUMNS FROM user;**
That would show you the info for the specific table.

To see the tables from the accounts database do: **SHOW TABLES FROM accounts;**

After that you can do an array and from there grab anything you want from within the query.

Hope this helps.